# JLine2: Got NPE when invoking ArgumentDelimiter

Tags: java, autocomplete, jline

Here is my code.

```
ConsoleReader console = new ConsoleReader();    
Completer quit = new StringsCompleter("quit");    
Completer subcommands = new ArgumentCompleter(new StringsCompleter("with-number"), new StringsCompleter("with-string"));
Completer add = new ArgumentCompleter(new StringsCompleter("add"), subcommands);
Completer delete = new ArgumentCompleter(new StringsCompleter("delete"), subcommands);    
Completer operations = new ArgumentCompleter(add, delete);    
Completer aggregated = new AggregateCompleter(new StringsCompleter("run"), quit, operations);
console.addCompleter(aggregated);
```

When I try to complete the command I get this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at jline.console.completer.ArgumentCompleter$AbstractArgumentDelimiter.delimit(ArgumentCompleter.java:283)
        at jline.console.completer.ArgumentCompleter.complete(ArgumentCompleter.java:116)
        at jline.console.completer.ArgumentCompleter.complete(ArgumentCompleter.java:152)
        at jline.console.completer.AggregateCompleter$Completion.complete(AggregateCompleter.java:121)
        at jline.console.completer.AggregateCompleter.complete(AggregateCompleter.java:80)
        at jline.console.ConsoleReader.complete(ConsoleReader.java:3261)
        at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2621)
        at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2269)
        at com.test.jline.JLineExample.main(JLineExample.java:41)
```

Code expected behavior:

```
> run [TAB]
  add delete
> run del[TAB]ete [TAB]
  with-number with-string
```

How can I fix my code to achieve that kind of behavior?

*PS*

I use `JLine 2.12`.

Comment: Did you try to change all `ArgumentCompleter` to `AggregateCompleter `?

Comment: Yes. I got the same error.